# Given the session key and secret, how can we decrypt Rails cookies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, encryption, cookies

I've got a question about how Rails handles cookie
encryption/decryption.

I've got this in my config/environment.rb

```
  config.action_controller.session = {
    :session_key => [some key],
    :secret => [some secret]
  }
```

And this in config/environment/production.rb et al.:

```
  ActionController::Base.session_options[:session_domain] = [some
domain]
```

So far, so good -- as long as all my Rails apps have the same
session_key and secret, and are on the same domain, they can all use
that same cookie.

However, a colleague now has a JSP application (on the same domain),
with which he'd like to read the cookies I have set.

So, given a secret and an encrypted cookie value, how would we decrypt
it to get the contents of that cookie?

(The docs seem to indicate this is one-way SHA1 encryption by default
-- http://caboo.se/doc/classes/CGI/Session/CookieStore.html -- but
then how would my Rails applications read the contents of a cookie
that is one-way encrypted?)

Thanks in advance for any tips/pointers/insight,

Joe

Comment: http://www.railshorde.com/blog/rails-decode-session-cookie

Answer (score 18):

If you pull the session.data field straight from the session data stored in your app's database (if you are using active_record_store in your environment.rb file)

```
config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store
```

... here is how you decode it and return the hash:

```
Marshal.load(ActiveSupport::Base64.decode64(@session.data))
```

... or in Rails >= 3.2 (thanks Chuck Vose)

```
Marshal.load(Base64.decode64(@session.data))
```

It is not encrypted at all.

Comment: Alas, I'm using cookies for the sessions on this particular project. I don't see anything database-specific in your line to decode it.

"Decrypt" is the wrong word; I should have said "decode".

Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: In Rails3.2 ActiveSupport is no longer the parent of Base64. Just delete ActiveSupport:: to make this work. Also worth noting that if you're debugging you can leave off the Marshal.load if it's giving you trouble.

Answer (score 14):

Rails uses HMAC-SHA1 for encrypting cookie data, which is different from a one-way SHA1 encryption, as you suspected (see [the Wikipedia article on HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) for an explanation). The encryption is done by the `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier` class (source code is fairly readable). Here's an example based on a test Rails app:

```
secret = 'b6ff5a9c3c97bf89afe9a72e6667bafe855390e8570d46e16e9760f6394' +
  '4ab05577b211ec2f43f6c970441518f0241775499bde055078f754c33b62f68ba27ca'

cookie = "_test_session=BAh7CCIYdXNlcl9jcmVkZW50aWFsc19pZGkGIhV1c2VyX2NyZW" +
  "RlbnRpYWxzIgGAMzBlODkxZDQ2MWZhNjFkMDFmNzczMmJjNDdjMjIwZGFjMTY2NWEwNDMwZ" +
  "DVjMmUxOWY5MDFjMjQ5NWQ4OTM1OGZlMzE3NzRiZTFiZjM1ZTVlZDY2ZGUzYTkwOWZjZTgw" +
  "NTFlNGUxZWI0MTUzYTRjODZiMGZmMzM3NzliM2U3YzI6D3Nlc3Npb25faWQiJTgxNzk0Yjd" +
  "kN2IxYzRjMDE0M2QwOTk5NTVjZjUwZTVm--25c8f3222ab1be9f2394e2795a9f2557b06d0a92"

session = cookie.split('=').last
verifier = ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier.new(secret, 'SHA1')
verifier.verify(session)
```

This should return the session hash you expect. To implement this in Java your colleague is going to have to duplicate the `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier#verify` method. Source code is in your gems directory (`/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems` on my system) at `activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb`.

Comment: I think your response is not quite right. HMAC-SHA1 is an algorithm which is used to verify the authenticity of a data string. It works by calculating a digest of the message using a one-way hash function, and with a digest generated when the message was created. There is no encryption going on.

Comment: If you get the error: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)`. It's because in Rails 6 the arguments for `MessageVerifier` have changed. Use `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier.new(secret, digest: 'SHA1')`. You can also leave off the `digest` option entirely since it defaults to `SHA1`

Answer (score 10):

Here's how to decrypt the session cookie in Rails 4

```
def decrypt_session_cookie(cookie)
  cookie = CGI.unescape(cookie)
  config = Rails.application.config

  encrypted_cookie_salt = config.action_dispatch.encrypted_cookie_salt               # "encrypted cookie" by default
  encrypted_signed_cookie_salt = config.action_dispatch.encrypted_signed_cookie_salt # "signed encrypted cookie" by default

  key_generator = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new(config.secret_key_base, iterations: 1000)
  secret = key_generator.generate_key(encrypted_cookie_salt)
  sign_secret = key_generator.generate_key(encrypted_signed_cookie_salt)

  encryptor = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(secret, sign_secret)
  encryptor.decrypt_and_verify(cookie)
end
```

http://big-elephants.com/2014-01/handling-rails-4-sessions-with-go/

Comment: I had to use `Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base` instead of `config.secret_key_base` (the latter was nil in the development environment) when creating the ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator to make it work.

Answer (score 8):

By default, Rails (before version 4) does not encrypt session cookies, it only signs them.  To encrypt them, you need to do something like this:

```
ActionController::Base.session_store = EncryptedCookieStore
```

There are multiple plugins that provide that kind of encryption functionality.

So, if you're not specifically using an encrypted store, all the Java code needs to do is verify the cookie signature and decode the cookie.  As Alex says in his answer, you would need to duplicate the functionality of `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier#verify`, and share the key with the Java application.  That both verifies and decodes the cookie.

If you don't want to verify the signature (which I do NOT recommend), you can use Midwire's method of decoding from Base64 to view the session hash.  In Ruby, this is:

```
Marshal.load(ActiveSupport::Base64.decode64(the_cookie_value))
```

I know this is old, but hope this helps somebody!

(Update: The question relates to Rails 3. Starting with Rails 4, session cookies are encrypted by default.)

Answer (score 1):

I've written a Ruby gem to handle cookies managed by Rails apps. Reading its source you can understand how it works and possibly port it to Java so that your JSP app could use that:

https://github.com/rosenfeld/rails_compatible_cookies_utils

It's a single file with ~ 150 lines of code which also handles signed only cookie values and takes care of both signing/encrypting and verifying/decrypting, while you seem to only be concerned about decrypting. This is the method for decrypting:

https://github.com/rosenfeld/rails_compatible_cookies_utils/blob/master/lib/rails_compatible_cookies_utils.rb#L41-L52

It worths mentioning that besides the key and the secret you'll also need to know which serializer is used. It used to be Marshal but it seems the default for newly generated apps is now JSON. If Marshal was used then it may be tricky to convert that code to Java as you'd have to find a library which implements Ruby's Marshal#load.

Comment: This was very useful, thanks. Checking out the source was much easier since it is more compact compared to other solutions and helped me duplicate your functionality in Elixir.

Comment: Yep, that was my idea. I thought people willing to implement the same logic in other languages would benefit from getting the logic all concentrated in a single point. Glad it helped you :)