# How Can I Access Rails' Session In My Java App

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, session

I have two web apps in one domain. One is written by ruby another is by java. And my rails app is using db session. So there have a "sessions" table in my database. What I want to do is reading the session info from this table in java.

Here is my problem: *Rails' sessions table is encrypted. So I can not read it directly from JDBC.*

I don't want to write a decrypt code to convert it. Because it's not a good idea to split one logic both in java and rails. So I hope to find a way to cancel the encrypt session data behavior in rails. Does anyone know how to wirte it in rails config file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encryption scheme isn't going to change in the Rails code, so it's not a horrible thing to implement the decryption in Java. If you want to take this route, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941499/given-the-session-key-and-secret-how-can-we-decrypt-rails-cookies). However, if you really want to prevent encryption, it's not well documented, but in `config/environment.rb` it would probably suffice to make sure that the hash in `config.action_controller.session` does not contain an entry with the key `:secret`. Make sure you secure your database with other means though!

Comment: I have to write the decryption code in java... Anyway, thank you btown!