# Sharing the session between Rails and Spring MVC

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring-mvc, session-cookies

In Rails session is stored in a cookie and signed to prevent forgery. I am looking if there are best practices around getting the Rails cookie (and thus session) loaded by Spring MVC in some way so that it can be read and used.

```
String[] parts = URLDecoder.decode(cookie).split("--");
byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(parts[0].getBytes());
String checksum = parts[1];
String decoded_string = new String(decoded);
```

This gives the serialized hash - but it would be ideal if this could be deserialized to a hash in Java. However, I was hoping others might have tested this or done something similar and can warn against potential pitfalls.

Related to: [How Can I Access Rails' Session In My Java App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967394/how-can-i-access-rails-session-in-my-java-app), [How do I manage sessions in a hybrid Ruby/GWT system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327752/how-do-i-manage-sessions-in-a-hybrid-ruby-gwt-system)

Comment: Down that road lies madness. Have you tried looking into something like CAS? http://www.jasig.org/cas

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example you can share some information between those applications using database, for example Redis or other key-value storage.