# How to make registration via API be able only for humans?

Tags: service, web

I making web service (JSON), and web site, which uses this service. And this web site uses service function "register" to register users in web site. And I dont want to make captcha because its boring  to type and easy to make mistakes while typing and I just can to loose my customers while registration procedure. So its easy to make application that will register [user00000@haha.com .. user99999@hehe.com] rage of fake accounts. How to avoid this without typing CAPTCHA?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to clarify: you're asking to make registration forms hard to spoof by bots without using CAPTCHA?

Comment: Can you use other technologies?
Things like this come to mind:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797513/user-registeration-form-without-captcha

Comment: 2Alex: No, I want registration form thats should be simple to human, but this reg form uses web service like site.com/register?login=ddd&pwd=666

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different approaches you can use, or a combination of them:

You can have your users perform basic math instead of the CAPTCHA.

You can also use javascript to detect bots, since bots typically use straight HTTP requests, however client-side javascript requires a real browser in order to execute:

http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/07/detecting-bots-in-javascrip/

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice alternatives to CAPTCHA, for example [this](http://areyouahuman.com/demo/) and [this](http://keypic.com/?tid=homepage_what_is) and [this](http://drivingtraffic.com/replace-capthca/) and [this](http://www.formarmor.com/) (btw, you can find different alternative-CAPTCHAs [here](http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/the-captcha-alternatives.html) - not all of them are "hard" to use!).
Also, there are some alternative CAPTCHAs that instead of displaying twisted characters - give you a simple arithmetic equation, for example: `3+7=` and you have to type in the correct result.