# Rails form in external site with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Basically I'm wondering if it's possible to have a form on a site outside of mail Rails app to POST to a form in my Rails app. For example (not what I'm going to be doing) a contact form on a Wordpress site, when submitted would POST the values to my Rails app. What would my steps be to make that possible? Or any references that are already out there?

OR if it's possible to load a form from my Rails to an outside site using Ajax or something. Eh that's probably a long shot but don't know what would be more secure and slim on code.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it with AJAX you may have to handle XSS issues. Maybe you need to write an easy API for your application that could be consumed from that other application. That's not difficult from Rails and you can get help from some good controller abstractions like [inherited_resources](http://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources).

At some point that external application will send a form to itself using AJAX and will handle it and send it to your rails application using JSON or XML... or whatever format you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Be aware that you'll have issues with the [form authenticity token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understand-rails-authenticity-token), so it might be easier to turn the token off.