# What is a CSRF token? What is its importance and how does it work?

Tags: csrf

I am writing an application (Django, it so happens) and I just want an idea of what actually a "CSRF token" is and how it protects the data.

Is the post data not safe if you do not use CSRF tokens?

Comment: It's a secret, user-specific token in all form submissions and side-effect URLs to prevent Cross-Site Request Forgeries.  More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: seems like there is a fine line between *protecting* a question and banning it for being too broad :D

Comment: From [OWASP Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet): "_Cross-Site Scripting is not necessary for CSRF to work. However, any cross-site scripting vulnerability can be used to defeat all CSRF mitigation techniques [...].This is because an XSS payload can simply read any page on the site using an XMLHttpRequest [...]. It is imperative that no XSS vulnerabilities are present to ensure that CSRF defenses can't be circumvented._"

Comment: This is a very good video example about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hW2ONyxAySY tl;dw: CSRF tokens make the requests input unpredictable a priori. Thus, an attacker can't easily reproduce it.

Answer (score 1905):

### Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) in simple words

- Assume you are currently logged into your online banking at `www.mybank.com`
- Assume a money transfer from `mybank.com` will result in a request of (conceptually) the form `http://www.mybank.com/transfer?to=<SomeAccountnumber>;amount=<SomeAmount>`. (Your account number is not needed, because it is implied by your login.)
- You visit `www.cute-cat-pictures.org`, not knowing that it is a malicious site.
- If the owner of that site knows the form of the above request (easy!) and correctly guesses you are logged into `mybank.com` (requires some luck!), they could include on their page a request like `http://www.mybank.com/transfer?to=123456;amount=10000` (where `123456` is the number of their Cayman Islands account and `10000` is an amount that you previously thought you were *glad* to possess).
- *You* retrieved that `www.cute-cat-pictures.org` page, so *your* browser will make that request.
- Your bank cannot recognize this origin of the request: Your web browser will send the request along with your `www.mybank.com` cookie and it will look perfectly legitimate. There goes your money!

This is the world **without CSRF tokens**.

Now for the better one ***with* CSRF tokens**:

- The transfer request is extended with a third argument: `http://www.mybank.com/transfer?to=123456;amount=10000;token=31415926535897932384626433832795028841971`.
- That token is a huge, impossible-to-guess random number that `mybank.com` will include on their own web page when they serve it to you. It is *different* each time they serve any page to anybody.
- The attacker is not able to guess the token, is not able to convince your web browser to surrender it (if the browser works correctly...), and so the attacker will *not* be able to create a valid request, because requests with the wrong token (or no token) will be refused by `www.mybank.com`.

Result: You keep your `10000` monetary units.

(Your mileage may vary.)

**EDIT from [comment worth reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207160/what-is-a-csrf-token-what-is-its-importance-and-how-does-it-work#comment68126014_33829607) by [SOFe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3990767/sofe):**

> It would be worthy to note that script from `www.cute-cat-pictures.org` normally does not have access to your anti-CSRF token from `www.mybank.com` because of HTTP access control. This note is important for some people who unreasonably send a header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` for every website response without knowing what it is for, just because they can't use the API from another website.

Comment: And obviously the token would ideally be named *anti*-CSRF token, but the name is probably complicated enough as it is.

Comment: @LutzPrechelt thank you. why can't javascript be able to obtain any authenticity tokens from the browser?

Comment: It would be worthy to note that script from `www.cute-cat-pictures.org` normally does not have access to your anti-CSRF token from `www.mybank.com` because of HTTP access control. This note is important for some people who unreasonably send a header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` for every website response without knowing what it is for, just because they can't use the API from another website.

Comment: Dear @LutzPrechelt Can you please following points: 1 - How to fake site finds the request URL pattern ? you mentioned easy. 2 - If they change the values of URL request, their scenario should still work or not ? for example amount = 2000 . if not , why ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "correctly guesses you are logged into mybank.com (requires some luck!)," — It doesn't need luck: They could brute force lots of online banks, and get lots of visitors. They only need to be lucky occasionally.

Comment: @Danial — 1. By using the site and looking at how it works. 2. Well yes, but its a hypothetical example anyway.

Comment: What prevents `www.cute-cat-pictures.org` from crawling `www.mybank.com` and get the CSRF token there? I mean, isn't it useful only for pages behind a login?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger: The crawled page would have a different CSRF token than the CSRF token served on the page of the user intending to transfer the amount.

Comment: How can a webpage in modern browser "guess" what other tabs you have opened, and how can quess you are logged into that pages? Via javascript I think it's impossible. Let's assume all websites have strict Same origin policy. Does CSRF attack presume, you have vulnerable or infected browser and / or computer?

Comment: @ MitjaGustin: The guessing is just assuming. Most often the assumption fails and the fake request does not work out, sometimes it is correct and the attack (without CSRF) succeeds.

Comment: So if I allow only www.mybank.com in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` , I don't have to worry about csrf token?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger If the attacker opens the webpage on his computer - since they do not have the cookie of the logged in user - they will not receive the corresponding csrf token (each csrf token should be valid only for specific user session). If the attacker tries to load the webpage containing the token on the computer of the user, with a script placed in cute-cat-pictures website, browser will prevent him to read the www.mybank.com (and the token) because of the same origin policy.

Comment: @LutzPrechelt I think it is not enough that the token is always different, it has to be paired with a session and the server has to check that the token it receives was generated for a session which the server identifies by the received cookie. Otherwise, the hacker can just visit mybank themselves and get some valid token. So if you use a new token with every form you have to save it paired with the sessionid on the server. It is probably easier to use the same token per session.

Comment: In your `You retrieved that www.cute-cat-pictures.org page, so your browser will make that request.`, do you mean from the `mybank.com` page to view a link to the `www.cute-cat-pictures.org` page?  the link is in the  `mybank.com`?

Comment: @MitjaGustin The guessing works this this: "Hmm, `mybank.com` is the biggest bank, so out of every 10 000 people visiting my `cute-cat-pictures`, about 500 will be `mybank` customers -- and if I'm a little lucky, 5 of them will be logged in to `mybank` at that time. Let's see..."

Comment: If a HttpGet request can modify the resource's state, csrf token stored in cookie won't do any help right?

Comment: Just pointing out that the number is not random and impossible to guess. In fact take any circle and divide perimeter by diameter :-)

Comment: Are you the author of this post? the content is the same: https://cloudunder.io/blog/csrf-token

Comment: i like this `just because they can't use the API from another website.`

Comment: @boctulus, I think you meant to post your comment on Dan's answer, [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49435939/3469273)?

Comment: So is the correct setting of Access-Control-Allow-Origin an alternative of including the CSRF-token?

Comment: Can mybank verify the origin header value to deny the request ? Origin value is set by browsers and in this case should be cute-cat-pictures.org

Comment: I didn't understand, the browser will automatically send the cookie of `www.mybank.com` in an request made in `www.cute-cat-pictures.org`?

Comment: @Ekaterina On the contrary Access-Control-Allow-Origin must be restricted for CSRF protection to actually work. Otherwise the malicious site could make a request to mybank and read the CSRF token in the response and then use it to conduct the fraud

Comment: @Leto Just adding to the clarification: cute-cat-pictures.org never gets to SEE your cookies, but it doesn't need to. It can force your browser to make a request to mybank.com, no different from a page opening a new tab when you click a link. This request can happen in the background. When your browser makes ANY request to mybank.com, it will automatically send any mybank cookies along with it. If that cookie includes a still valid login session, then the request can include malicious instructions. CSRF protection is a two-part paradigm involving the tokens AND restricted origins in HTTP.

Comment: @Austin In the scenario of making a request to mybank.com from cute-cat-pictures.org, what will the mybank.com server see as the Origin header of the request?

Comment: What can't wrap my head around is: if the browser willingly sends all the `www.mybank.com` cookies to the bank server, why wouldn't that just happen for the crsf-token as well? I'ld expect it to be send altogether with the session data.

Comment: @NotX The CSRF token is part of the form data (this is a `POST` request), not in a cookie. The attacker produces all form data without help from the `www.mybank.com` server and so lacks the CSRF token.

Comment: @Marcel RE: "I think it is not enough that the token is always different..." true, which is why many sites require the token to be sent in a custom header.  Then, a malicious website can't send it due to cross-origin custom header restriction.

Answer (score 233):

Yes, the post data is safe. But the origin of that data is not. This way somebody can trick user with JS into logging in to your site, while browsing attacker's web page.

In order to prevent that, django will send a random key both in cookie, and form data.
Then, when users POSTs, it will check if two keys are identical. In case where user is tricked, 3rd party website cannot get your site's cookies, thus causing auth error.

Comment: @DmitryShevchenko Hi, trying to understand how is this method of cookie+form-input different from just validating the referrer on the server side? All the examples that I find is related to a hacker tricking the user to post from his site to the actual site.

Comment: Ok, I found out why the referrer is not used. It's blocked in many cases as it's considered to hold sensitive information sometimes. Corporates and their proxies typically do that. However, if HTTPS is used, then there is more likelihood that it will not be blocked.

Comment: It's easy to change referrer, I would not say that it is a reliable piece of information. CSRF token, however, is generated using server secret key and usually tied to the user

Comment: I don't really understand why this is a security threat. The user will be logged into another site... but the original site won't have any way to retrieve that information. Right?

Comment: Well, suppose I inject a malicious iframe of "http://bank.com/transfer?from=x&to=y" in a, say, Facebook.com. If you're customer of bank.com and you go to Facebook, that iframe will load bank page, with your cookies (because browser will send them along to a known domain) and make a money transfer. Without you knowing anything.

Answer (score 98):

[The Cloud Under blog has a good explanation of CSRF tokens.](https://web.archive.org/web/20190706194107/https://cloudunder.io/blog/csrf-token) (archived)

> Imagine you had a website like a simplified Twitter, hosted on a.com.
> Signed in users can enter some text (a tweet) into a form that’s being
> sent to the server as a POST request and published when they hit the
> submit button. On the server the user is identified by a cookie
> containing their unique session ID, so your server knows who posted
> the Tweet.
>
> The form could be as simple as that:
>
> ```
>  <form action="http://a.com/tweet" method="POST">
>    <input type="text" name="tweet">
>    <input type="submit">
>  </form>
> ```

> Now imagine, a bad guy copies and pastes this form to his malicious
> website, let’s say b.com. The form would still work. As long
> as a user is signed in to your Twitter (i.e. they’ve got a valid
> session cookie for a.com), the POST request would be sent to
> `http://a.com/tweet` and processed as usual when the user clicks the
> submit button.
>
> So far this is not a big issue as long as the user is made aware about
> what the form exactly does, but what if our bad guy tweaks the form
> like this:
>
> ```
>  <form action="https://example.com/tweet" method="POST">
>    <input type="hidden" name="tweet" value="Buy great products at http://b.com/#iambad">
>    <input type="submit" value="Click to win!">
>  </form>
> ```

> Now, if one of your users ends up on the bad guy’s website and hits
> the “Click to win!” button, the form is submitted to
> your website, the user is correctly identified by the session ID in
> the cookie and the hidden Tweet gets published.
>
> If our bad guy was even worse, he would make the innocent user submit
> this form as soon they open his web page using JavaScript, maybe even
> completely hidden away in an invisible iframe. This basically is
> cross-site request forgery.
>
> A form can easily be submitted from everywhere to everywhere.
> Generally that’s a common feature, but there are many more cases where
> it’s important to only allow a form being submitted from the domain
> where it belongs to.
>
> Things are even worse if your web application doesn’t distinguish
> between POST and GET requests (e.g. in PHP by using $_REQUEST instead
> of $_POST). Don’t do that! Data altering requests could be submitted
> as easy as `<img src="http://a.com/tweet?tweet=This+is+really+bad">`,
> embedded in a malicious website or even an email.
>
> How do I make sure a form can only be submitted from my own website?
> This is where the CSRF token comes in. A CSRF token is a random,
> hard-to-guess string. On a page with a form you want to protect, the
> server would generate a random string, the CSRF token, add it to the
> form as a hidden field and also remember it somehow, either by storing
> it in the session or by setting a cookie containing the value. Now the
> form would look like this:
>
> ```
>     <form action="https://example.com/tweet" method="POST">
>       <input type="hidden" name="csrf-token" value="nc98P987bcpncYhoadjoiydc9ajDlcn">
>       <input type="text" name="tweet">
>       <input type="submit">
>     </form>
> ```

> When the user submits the form, the server simply has to compare the
> value of the posted field csrf-token (the name doesn’t
> matter) with the CSRF token remembered by the server. If both strings
> are equal, the server may continue to process the form. Otherwise the
> server should immediately stop processing the form and respond with an
> error.
>
> Why does this work? There are several reasons why the bad guy from our
> example above is unable to obtain the CSRF token:
>
> Copying the static source code from our page to a different website
> would be useless, because the value of the hidden field changes with
> each user. Without the bad guy’s website knowing the current user’s
> CSRF token your server would always reject the POST request.
>
> Because the bad guy’s malicious page is loaded by your user’s browser
> from a different domain (b.com instead of a.com), the bad guy has no
> chance to code a JavaScript, that loads the content and therefore our
> user’s current CSRF token from your website. That is because web
> browsers don’t allow cross-domain AJAX requests by default.
>
> The bad guy is also unable to access the cookie set by your server,
> because the domains wouldn’t match.
>
> When should I protect against cross-site request forgery? If you can
> ensure that you don’t mix up GET, POST and other request methods as
> described above, a good start would be to protect all POST requests by
> default.
>
> You don’t have to protect PUT and DELETE requests, because as
> explained above, a standard HTML form cannot be submitted by a browser
> using those methods.
>
> JavaScript on the other hand can indeed make other types of requests,
> e.g. using jQuery’s $.ajax() function, but remember, for AJAX requests
> to work the domains must match (as long as you don’t explicitly
> configure your web server otherwise).
>
> This means, often you do not even have to add a CSRF token to AJAX
> requests, even if they are POST requests, but you will have to make
> sure that you only bypass the CSRF check in your web application if
> the POST request is actually an AJAX request. You can do that by
> looking for the presence of a header like X-Requested-With, which AJAX
> requests usually include. You could also set another custom header and
> check for its presence on the server side. That’s safe, because a
> browser would not add custom headers to a regular HTML form submission
> (see above), so no chance for Mr Bad Guy to simulate this behaviour
> with a form.
>
> If you’re in doubt about AJAX requests, because for some reason you
> cannot check for a header like X-Requested-With, simply pass the
> generated CSRF token to your JavaScript and add the token to the AJAX
> request. There are several ways of doing this; either add it to the
> payload just like a regular HTML form would, or add a custom header to
> the AJAX request. As long as your server knows where to look for it in
> an incoming request and is able to compare it to the original value it
> remembers from the session or cookie, you’re sorted.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info.
During the post request , the site has to send the  csrf token to the server, so when will the client send this csrf token to the server? Is it while making the preflight options request? Please elablorate on this part..

Comment: @Dan How come b.com can access the cookies of another site a.com?

Comment: great explanation!

Comment: But where does one get the token? Which request usually returns it?

Comment: Nice explanation. I have one question:- So CSRF token is valid per request or per user and changes after each request ?

Comment: @AliAbbas, Yes, CSRF should be valid for one request only.

Comment: @zakir that's the same question I got, I have just read five articles on CSRF, yet I don't know how come that the browser sends another domain's cookies

Answer (score 86):

The site generates a unique token when it makes the form page.  This token is required to post/get data back to the server.

Since the token is generated by your site and provided only when the page with the form is generated, some other site can't mimic your forms -- they won't have the token and therefore can't post to your site.

Comment: Could a user grab the token output within the source, grab the cookie sent to them and then from a 3rd party site submit?

Comment: @JackMarchetti yes. but it would be costly since every time you wanted to submit the form from a 3rd party site you'd have to load the page and parse out the token.  CSRF tokens should be ideally coupled with other forms of security if you're concerned with this vector of attack

Comment: I have the same question as @JackMarchetti, whats not clear is - if the CSRF token changes on each login. If it stays the same, what would prevent an attacker from first logging in, grabbing the request token, and then inserting that token in the attack?

Comment: @PaulPreibisch it should change on each page load - not on each login.  This way the attacker would have to request the page each time they wanted to submit the form. Makes it much more difficult.

Comment: @tkone, It doesn't really make it much more difficult. If just doubles the amount of effort and time. It doesn't add any kind of prohibitive processing. The trick is also associating the CSRF token to a domain-specific cookie, and sending this cookie along with the form. Both the cookie and the form post data would have to be sent to the server on the POST request. This way would require a Cookie-Hijacking attack to be able to emulate a legitimate request.

Comment: Just forcing the attacker to make an additional request to fetch the token would not provide much protection really. The actual protection results from properly configured access control, which prevents the page (and token) to be retrieved from another domain. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207160/what-is-a-csrf-token-what-is-its-importance-and-how-does-it-work#comment68126014_33829607) explains it well.

Answer (score 11):

The root of it all is to make sure that the requests are coming from the actual users of the site. A csrf token is generated for the forms and Must be tied to the user's sessions. It is used to send requests to the server, in which the token validates them. This is one way of protecting against csrf, another would be checking the referrer header.

Comment: Do not rely on the referer header, it can easily be faked.

Comment: This is the correct answer! The token MUST be tied to a session on the server. Comparing Cookie + Form data like the most up voted answer suggests is completely wrong. These components both form part of the request, which the client constructs.

Comment: Actually, no. The token MUST be tied to each REQUEST to the Server.  If you only tie it to the session, then you run the risk of someone stealing the session's token and submitting a request with that token. So for max safety the  token must be tied to each http requiest.