# Spring security always returns HTTP 403

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have configured a custom `Filter` that grants a spring authority for every URL other than `/login` :

```
public class TokenFilter implements Filter {
     @Override
     public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
          GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("myAuthority");
          UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, token, Arrays.asList(authority));
          SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
      }
}
```

and a spring configuration that protects all requests (but /`login`) with that authority :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().hasAuthority("myAuthority");
    }

}
```

But every request except `/login` gets a HTTP `403` Forbidden.

I have debugged and made sure the code from the filter is really triggered.

What could be the problem?

EDIT - when putting spring security logs in debug I get the following stack trace :

```
2015-07-31 14:52:42 [http-nio-8002-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Accès refusé
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at com.kgwebapps.tonpronostic.security.TokenFilter.doFilter(TokenFilter.java:55) [classes/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1720) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]
```

Comment: Can you please put some stacktrace? Thanks.

Comment: There is no exception thrown

Comment: please enable debug logging for org.springframework.security. Then when you get the 403, copy the last 10-20 lines in the debug log from your IDE console.

Comment: Ok thanks, just added it to the question.

Comment: As the log says, you are not logged in. Your configuration seems wrong. I have not that much idea about Java based configurations as I am using XML based. You can check out some examples. Secondly, instead of adding authority as 'myAuthority', please add something relevant like ROLE_USER.

Comment: You've declared a custom filter, but you have not added it to your config `http.addFilter(new TokenFilter())`. Also check out [`addFilterBefore(...)`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/HttpSecurityBuilder.html#addFilterBefore%28javax.servlet.Filter,%20java.lang.Class%29) or [`addFilterAfter(...)`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/HttpSecurityBuilder.html#addFilterAfter%28javax.servlet.Filter,%20java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: Thanks Roman Vottner it worked! But before doing that it was already declared as a @component and effectively executed. Did it not work because of filter order? Or does 'http.addFilter' do something special more that just registering the filter?

Comment: I'm not aware of that filters are auto-discoverable at all. Pre Java-based web-configuration you needed to declare filters in XML via `<filter><filter-name>customFilter</filter-name><filter-class>com.yourcompany.CustomFilter</filter-class></filter>` also

Comment: Interesting thing regarding slashes - probably will be useful for someone, we migrated to Spring Boot 3.* and it turned out that requests from FE /login/ are responded with 403 because of trailing slash (on the BE we have /login), however it was ok before. So trailing slashes matter!

Answer (score 85):

I have the same issue to you, every request is blocked by 403 error, except the [/] request. After a lot of time in crazy, I found the root cause, that is the [csrf].
Then my security config is like as following:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/delete/**").authenticated()
      .and()
      .httpBasic().and()
      .csrf().disable();
}
```

This configuration says that: only [delete/**] should be authorized.
And I mark the [delete] action as following:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
void delete(String id);
```

Hope to help someone.

Comment: i think you can add the role in same configuration: authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/delete/**")
                .hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")

Comment: is it secure to disable csrf?

Comment: @user666 Simple answer: no, it is not secure. However when your website does not allow user to modify any data (save/update their data in database etc) then it could be secure (basically when you only allow GET requests) since the purpose of `csrf` protection is to prevent malicious websites from doing requests on user's behalf. [Good post about csrf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207160/what-is-a-csrf-token-what-is-its-importance-and-how-does-it-work).

Answer (score 8):

The only (obvious) thing that might result to 403 is the users role is not set to `ROLE_myAuthority`.

Comment: I have changed my role name from USER to ROLE_USER in DB and it works. Thanks @Link

Comment: it works for me too, ROLE_USER in DB and USER in java code as a role

Answer (score 7):

As others have said 403 means that user is logged in but doesn't have the right permission to view the resource; I would check the following:

1. Your control has the correct role permission
   `@Secured( {"ROLE_myAuthority"} )`
2. You had actually granted the correct permission `new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_myAuthority");`
3. Actual granted authority from the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken object
4. Filter is been injected correctly

   ```
   Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, authentication.getCredentials(), authorities);  
   Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> auths = auth.getAuthorities();`

   Iterator authsIterator = auths.iterator();

   while (authsIterator.hasNext()) {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority sga =  (SimpleGrantedAuthority) authsIterator.next();
           sga.getAuthority();
       // ... 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Confusingly Spring Security also returns 403 instead of 404 for all undefined endpoints if any restricting auth rule is set in the `SecurityFilterChain`.

So if you mistype a test url or (like me) forget to scan the the base package of the controller, this might set you on a wild-goose chase.

eg. this correctly returns `404` if I call an undefined endpoint:

```java
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
        .anyRequest().permitAll();
    return http.build();
}
```

While this returns `403` for the same call:

```java
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers(GET, "/health/**").permitAll();
    return http.build();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

IDK is it meet topic question or not, but I didn't find any similar subject so I'll leave it here.

I have pretty same situation: fully custom filter based on headers token authorization and always receiving 403

That's what worked for me:

```
http.csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()

                .addFilterBefore(XAuthTokenFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
```

Also a good idea to use in your application config:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: TRACE
```

to see what's going on inside filter chain.

Hope it will save somebody's time

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is a very old question but I just had the same error and I didn't find any solution on the internet.
It is correct that **403** means that the user is **authenticated** but **not authorized** to get a resource. This is related to the claims part in your JWT.
Your JWT builder needs to set proper **claims** for the user :

```
List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = AuthorityUtils
                .commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");

Jwts.builder()//
                .setIssuer(...)//
                .setSubject(...)//
                .setAudience(...)

                // This is the part that you missed

                .claim("authorities",
                        grantedAuthorities.stream()
                        .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))

                // Ends here

                .setIssuedAt(date)//
                .setExpiration(new Date(date.getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, signingKey)//
                .compact();
```

My WebSecurity configuration :

```
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

...

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()//
                .authorizeRequests()//
                .antMatchers(...).permitAll()//
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()//
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterAfter(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Comment: Hey, can you provide me with your source code or the code for the filter? I'm kinda stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

For people using Spring security 6+ here is the answer, think abour adding the permitAll() AND the csrf :

```
    @Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            ).csrf(csrf -> csrf
            .ignoringRequestMatchers("/**") );


    return http.build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting a 403 instead of a 401 usually means that you were logged in but you are not permitted (via authority) to see a resource.

Debug and confirm that the user you are logging in has that authority (I know your code sets it, but maybe you are setting something else wrong).

Comment: Ok but where can I check for it? The code doing that is somewhere down in spring security, i don't understand the framework well enough to know where to look.

Comment: On your debugger, use "Step Into" instead of "Step Over".

Answer (score 0):

`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` extends `AbstractAuthenticationToken`, `AbstractAuthenticationToken` implements `Authentication`.

[Spring security call `Authentication's` method `isAuthenticated()` to check whether it should be pass](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html#isAuthenticated--).

So you should call `setAuthenticated` of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` instance and set the argument `true`.

Like this:

```
public class TokenFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("myAuthority");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, token, Arrays.asList(authority));

        auth.setAuthenticated(true);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question but just in case someone stumble upon this post, an application had the same problem and it turns out to be an issue with `@ControllerAdvice`.

Basically, the setup was like this:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
class MainController {
```

```java
@PreAuthorize("...")
class AdminController extends MainController {
```

And for a strange reason, any controller extending from `MainController` would trigger the `@PreAuthorize` of the `AdminController` class even though there were no relationships between this controller and the latter.

In my case, it was an easy fix as removing the `@ControllerAdvice` was enough but if you need `@ControllerAdvice`, you might move the annotation to a class that is never used as a superclass.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a similar problem that I had by having the `server.servlet.context-path` configured in your `application.yml`

In my case, the `server.servlet.context-path` is configured to be `/api` and I expose the following endpoints below like so:

```
.requestMatchers("/api/health", "/api/ping").permitAll()
```

However, this won't work as spring security doesn't put the `context-path` into consideration so you have to omit that when specifying the endpoints.

```
.requestMatchers("/health", "/ping").permitAll()
```

Answer (score -2):

Add "/styles/*" for CSS files

http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests->requests                          .requestMatchers("/login","/register","/styles/*").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()