# Curl login php with hidden form

Tags: php, curl

i want to use curl to some site. But the site is required a hidden form.
Form HTML is like this:

```
<form method="get" name="login" action="example.com/procced.php">
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your email address" required /><br/>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
    <input type="text" name="request_token" id="request_token" value="5433db648b28c3aaffcf63e650541c37aaa34614" style="display: none"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>
```

how i curl php with that hidden form (name="requrest_token")

Comment: why you want to use CURL for this, i think its very simple, try to use AJAX

Comment: i want to curl to other website

Comment: Like any other form data.

Comment: but,request_token is generate randomly

Comment: This is most likely a [CSRF token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207160/what-is-a-csrf-token-what-is-its-importance-and-how-does-it-work). If so, doing a `curl` will not work as the back-end will prevent you from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
$url = "otherwebsiterul";  // url where you want to access 
$data = $_POST; // your form data as you want to pass.
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($handle);
```

Comment: Yes,but one of all is.request_token is requred.How i get request_token to curl this with this data?

Comment: do you want to access any cpanel?

Comment: i want to access my account in other website.

Comment: It's likely login to facebook using curl

Comment: and you get request_token in get method?