# What is the use of " Nonces " and is it mandatory to implement on every form like contact us?

Tags: security, nonce

I am currently working on sql injection prevention and cross side scripting prevention on contact us form (which has few input fields)and it sends data to the server.Is it required to implement Nonces? and what is the main purpose of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a CSRF token ? What is its importance and how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207160/what-is-a-csrf-token-what-is-its-importance-and-how-does-it-work)