# Is it okay to disable CSRF for slack slash command api mad in Django?

Tags: django, csrf, slack, slack-commands

Is it disabling CSRF functionality the best practice for Slack slash command server?

I want to call an API view function in Django by a [Slack slash command](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands), for example, `/test`.

When I call the URL for the view function with any browser (so it is a GET request), it works as expected.

However, when I run `/test` in Slack, I got `403_client_error` in slack, and `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set)` in the Django shell.

I believe this is because Slack sends a POST request, and Django requires CSRF token for any POST requests.

My question is whether I should disable CSRF checking for this view. Will there be a significant risk? Or is there any workaround?

Comment: I can disable CSRF by adding `@csrf_exempt` on top of my view and then the slack command works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

Yes, it's fine for an API endpoint.

**Longer Answer:**

Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Tokens are a means of preventing CSRF Attacks. These attacks basically work by placing some malicious code on another site that runs when the user visits that site. Upon loading the malicious site, some JavaScript code runs and submits a POST request to a site that the victim is already authenticated at. Since the user is already authenticated, the server for the other site—a bank, for example—thinks that the user is actually making this request—send the attacker $100, for example—and goes ahead and processes the request. Here is a really good description of CSRF Attacks and Tokens: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33829607/8068625

The way that CSRF Tokens prevent this is by putting a token somewhere on any page that contains a form and that token gets submitted as an additional field on the form when submitted. This way the page must actually be visited (which the attacker should not be able to accomplish) in order to submit the page.

So, as long as this page you are removing the CSRF protection from does not have a form on it that you would not like submitted by an attacker, it is fine to add `@csrf_exempt` to the view. It seems that this is the case since the endpoint exists solely as an API endpoint for a Slack Slash Command.

You might consider adding some other form of authentication for your API endpoints (note that CSRF is not for use in APIs) like, for example, [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/). But that is up to you.