# post instagram comment programmatically with js

Tags: javascript, instagram

I'm creating an instagram bot that posts a comment on a user's photo. I'm aware there are already solutions like [InstaPy](https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy) but it isn't working for me and I'm 99% complete with my own js solution.

Is there a way for me to post programmatically? I already set the textArea.value and I tried to submit the wrapping form (it just refreshes the page). I also tried to "click" the submit button but it isn't causing it to do anything. I also tried to "type" into the textarea but it seems that isn't possible without any actual user interaction on the screen as well as trying to submit the actual request (seems my headers don't match up and I'm getting a 403 error.) Below is a code snippet of what I'm currently doing.

```
var commentTextArea = document.getElementsByClassName('Ypffh')[0];
if (commentTextArea) {

    // Text area for posting comment
    commentTextArea.textContent = "This is my comment :)";

    setTimeout(function() {

        // Comment submit button
        var submitButton = document.getElementsByClassName('LCjcc')[0];
        submitButton.disabled = false;
        submitButton.click(); // doesn't fire anything. I can see in chrome dev tools there is no event event attached to this even when enabled which is odd

        // Comment form
        // Submitting form expectedly refreshes page
        // Tried add my own submit listener with return false && e.preventDefault and neither worked
        var form = document.querySelector('X7cDz');
        if (form) {

            form.submit();
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: code sample....

Comment: @DenisTsoi done :)

Comment: Instagram is probably detecting that you are using a robot.

Comment: did you solved it ?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 403 error because you do not submit csrf token. You can read about it more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207160/what-is-a-csrf-token-what-is-its-importance-and-how-does-it-work)

In order to overcome this challenge, you can use libraries that provide a high-level API to control browsers like [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer). This allows you to write a script which will run a browser and will act like a real user, surfing pages and leaving comments wherever you want.

Here is an example of code that signs into the Instagram and leaves a comment under a specific post:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  // Starting browser
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Login flow
  await page.goto('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher');
  await page.waitForSelector('input[name="username"]');
  await page.type('input[name="username"]', 'username');
  await page.type('input[name="password"]', 'password');
  await page.click('button[type="submit"]');

  // Waiting for page to refresh
  await page.waitForNavigation();

  // Navigate to post and submitting the comment
  await page.goto('https://www.instagram.com/p/BVSCQI-FRaj/');
  await page.waitForSelector('textarea');
  await page.type('textarea', 'Test comment');

  await page.click('button[type="submit"]');

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Just for Knowledge. Is it possible to get instagram like/follower without bot. Pure Coding (API or something) if you can help or suggest? Thanks

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Please, take a look at the [instagram developer documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/). It provides appropriate API. However, as far as I rememeber it requires OAuth authorization to be used

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Quickly i have gone through the documentation and found that it gives me the endpoint for GET USER & MEDIA. But I haven't found anything related to LIKES(I dont want the counts). if you suggest or we can connect on email or anywhere if possible for you.

Comment: Media response contains information about likes (counts only). You can follow `https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/` and check `GET/users/self/media/recent` response example. If you want to find information about who exactly put the likes I think this information is not available through the API unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you very much @SergeyMell Yeah...Thats y i believe that only automation is possible incase of likes (i know that some team can sit create accounts and do likes which is not cup of my tea anyways)