# How i can secure my post value within form while action on another file which is saving these value in mysql database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form which is getting user personal information with a `POST` method and action on another file which is validating all `POST` values and then store them into a `MySQL` database.

But now the problem is that someone can directly target my action or validation file which has query to insert data into database. So someone can directly use my action file and save their fake values into my `database`.

**Example:** If someone is inserting multiple entries within a second into the database directly, but the point is that when I delete the form action file from my website which is running, then the fake entries are stopped but when i upload again, my action file is on the website server and then fake entries can start again.
Can someone guide me on how i can fix this issue?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a CSRF token.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a CSRF token ? What is its importance and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207160/what-is-a-csrf-token-what-is-its-importance-and-how-does-it-work)