# How can I log into a website with Python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to log into "https://partner.getyourguide.com/en-us/login" using `requests` module in Python I keep getting the error `'Invalid CSRF token'` but the cookie doesn't have a `'Invalid CSRF token'`.

I'm expecting a `200` response for  successfully login but I get `403`

```
import requests as r
session = r.Session()
re= r.get('https://partner.getyourguide.com/en-us/login')
re.cookies

datad = {'email':'hello@world.com','password':'passowr'}  
response = r.post('https://partner.getyourguide.com/en-us/login', data = datad)
print(response)
```

Comment: First get to know what's CSRF token is and what it is for. It's standard knowledge if you have to deal with WWW forms https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207160/what-is-a-csrf-token-what-is-its-importance-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) token is hidden in the page.  Do a "view source" on the page and search for "csrf".

In order to have any chance of this working, you'll need to parse the page and then submit that CSRF token as another entry in `datad`.  You may run into other issues, as I'm betting that form submission is handled through JavaScript.