# Python POST requests return with "Response 400"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, http-post

I am trying to login on a website by use method requests POST.

```py
ssn = requests.session()
data = {"LoginForm[email]":"gmail@gmail.com", "LoginForm[password]":"pw12345", "LoginForm[rememberMe]":0}
r = ssn.post("https://www.fshare.vn/site/login", data = data)
print(r.json)

# bound method Response.json of <Response [400]>
```

as I know, I missing a value in data is called "csrf-app" : 
[HTTP Header POST : _csrf-app=gXvuYHZnQpoA37zC1Yncpb1BMstVUqRcVdj9x1QHJqK1AoYoHlUV21G9jaya0Jjy9iJRrz1_nRIft4ywO0RD-g==&LoginForm[email]=gmail@gmail.com&LoginForm[password]=pw12345&LoginForm[rememberMe]=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae12w.png)

So how to get this value ""csrf-app" to post that along the other data ?

Answer (score 0):

CSRF is used to avoid someone calling the APIs without the form.
You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207160/what-is-a-csrf-token-what-is-its-importance-and-how-does-it-work) for more information. You should instead look for their login REST APIs, and see if they have any.