# How can add product to the cart using ajax in django?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views, django-templates

**Problem**
*I want to add the product to the cart using ajax so that the page is not reloaded or refreshed and a popup is shown that the product is added to the cart.*

**Script**

```
$(document).on("click",".Id_submit",function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var selector = $(this).closest(".productID")
      console.log(selector.find("form").attr('action'))
      $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url: selector.find("form").attr('action'),
        success: function()
        {
          alert("Product added to cart")
        }
      });
```

**html**

```
<form id='transactionIDValue' class="d-inline" method="post">
              {{cart_product_form}}
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow px-5 py-2 Id_submit" value="Add To Cart">
              
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(transactions, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'])
    print(cart)

    # request.session['items_total'] = cart.product.count()
    return HttpResponse('success')
```

**urls.py**

```
extra_patterns = [
    path('add/carts/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_add, name='cart_add'),
]

urlpatterns=[
   
    path ('add/',include(extra_patterns)),
]
```

**Error**
*This is the errror I'm facing `Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /cart/add/add/carts/16/`*
*The issue I'm facing is that using the script it goes the cart url but the product is not added and in the console it shows that the url is forbidden. So, can someone help me with this issue please.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this.

A lot of people will recommend just adding the decorator `@csrf_exempt` to the view like:

```py
@require_POST
@csrf_exempt
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    ...
```

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207160/what-is-a-csrf-token-what-is-its-importance-and-how-does-it-work) on why this is a bad idea generally, but you can draw your own conclusions in how you want to protect your app.

The best thing to do is to submit the csrf_token field value with the js:

```js
$(document).on("click",".Id_submit",function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var selector = $(this).closest(".productID")
      console.log(selector.find("form").attr('action'))
      const form_data = {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('#transactionIDValue input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
      }
      $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url: selector.find("form").attr('action'),
        data: form_data,
        success: function()
        {
          alert("Product added to cart")
        }
      });
```

Comment: Is this ```{{cart_product_form}}``` making an issue, because quantity value is not getting cart_add views function and the product is not added properly.

Comment: yes ```{{cart_product_form}}``` is not working due to which it never adds the product to the cart and always show the previous products in the cart.

Comment: But the request succeeds yes? `200` response?

Comment: yes but the value is from ```cart_product_form``` is not added

Comment: In this it never enters the form validation check in the cart_add function in views