# CakePHP 3 CSRF token error on callbackURL

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, paytm

I have integrated the Paytm with Cakephp. Its working okay. But on call back url it set a page link . But on return its give me error of "CSRF token".

I am trying to disable csrf but its not working

```
$this->eventManager()->off($this->Csrf);
```

Comment: Please paste the relevant part of the code, and always report the error message in full. Instead of creating a workaround by disabling security features - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33829607/3679111 .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.