# confusion about Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Attack

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, csrf, csrf-token

I am reading [csrf attack explanation](https://www.synopsys.com/glossary/what-is-csrf.html#:%7E:text=Cross%2DSite%20Request%20Forgery%20(CSRF)%20is%20an%20attack%20that,has%20in%20an%20authenticated%20user.) but I'm confused how adding a csrf token prevents it.

Suppose this scenario, a bank website adds a CSRF token in all its transaction forms. A user enters an active session and opens a phishing website.

The phishing website secretly fetches a get request to the bank website to get the form, and extracts the CSRF token.

Then phishing website generates a fake post request for a transaction and passed CSRF token in.

Since the user is in the same active session, then the CSRF token is unchanged.
Wouldn't this break the CSRF Attack prevention scheme?

Answer (score 0):

The CSRF token is tied to the user's particular browser. The phishing website cannot grab the CSRF token from the user's browser unless the user's browser has a serious issue.

This question has already been answered in more detail here:

[What is a CSRF token? What is its importance and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207160/what-is-a-csrf-token-what-is-its-importance-and-how-does-it-work)