# rails 3 authenticity_token how it is generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

does any one know how the authenticity_token of rails3 is generated?
I noticed that the value of the token of a form does not change when I refresh the form page. 
who is it generated? based on session cookie? on time? secret_key?

Comment: This answer should have everything you need to know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understand-rails-authenticity-token

Comment: that does not give details on how the token is generated. which elements are used to ensure the unicity and the security of this token.

Comment: @enenkey :- do you got the answer to your question ??? if yes then please share it

Answer (score 6):

The `AuthenticityToken` is basically a call to  `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.base64(32)`, which you can read about here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SecureRandom.html

**Edit** - Updated to include more recent changes, as per Lambart's answer below.

In Rails >= 3.1, ActiveSupport::SecureRandom is deprecated in favor of SecureRandom from the Ruby standard library (starting with Ruby 1.9.3, it seems).

However it is generated, this token is stored in the session (i.e. it lasts for the lifetime of the session).

Thanks [Lambart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1339923/lambart).

Comment: Can you explain why the token is not changing after page refresh (F5) ? Is it because I'm in dev environment?

Comment: It is stored in the session, so it is not meant to change for the lifetime of the session, no matter what environment you're in.

Comment: Moderators didn't like my edit to update and fix the broken link in Fareesh's otherwise-informative (but dated) answer, so I guess I'd better just write my own.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails < 3.09, the `AuthenticityToken` is generated by a call to `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.base64(32)`, which you can read about [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/SecureRandom/base64/class).

In Rails >= 3.1, `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom` is deprecated in favor of [SecureRandom](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/SecureRandom) from the Ruby standard library (starting with Ruby 1.9.3, it seems).

However it is generated, this token is stored in the session (i.e. it lasts for the lifetime of the session).