# What happens to rails authenticity token after refresh and when it is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to know when does a authentication token in rails is generated again. Because whenever I refresh the page token doesn't changes? and I want to know when it will change again

possible duplicate:

> [rails 3 authenticity_token how it is generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968106/rails-3-authenticity-token-how-it-is-generated#comment18079544_6968106)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails authenticity token is used for [CSRF protection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf). It's stored in session ([source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L176)) and it'll be regenerated only when session is destroyed (e.g. when you close browser or clear session cookie).