# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken exception in safari while using iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, safari, cross-domain, p3p

While I posted a form from iframe in safari, it gives Invalid Authenticity Token exception. If I try without iframe, then it works fine.

Why it is happening? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The authenticity token is a mechanism that rails uses to protect users from CSRF attacks. Here is a good explanation, taken from [Understanding the Rails Authenticity Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understand-rails-authenticity-token)

> When the user views a form to create, update, or destroy
>   a resource, the rails app would create a random authenticity_token,
>   store this token in the session, and place it in a hidden field in the
>   form. When the user submits the form, rails would look for the
>   authenticity_token, compare it to the one stored in the session, and
>   if they match the request is allowed to continue.

So basically, for any action that would modify your model rails wants to verify that it is a change originated by you.

Rails does that (through the use of `form_for` or `form_tag` helpers) by adding that secret authenticity token to the form with a html tag like this: `<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="Som3Thin10ngAndUGly">`

Back to your problem: I've never worked with iframes so I'm not sure what's happening, but my guess is that your iframe form is not passing the authencity_token. If this is the case the solution is simple, just add a hidden input like the one above and use the `form_authenticity_token` method to set its value.