# Rails: How Does csrf_meta_tag Work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

I'm a PHP developer learning Ruby on Rails by reading [Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). Here is a quote from the book, referring to `csrf_meta_tag`:

> ...the Rails method `csrf_meta_tag` [prevents] cross-site request
>   forgery (CSRF), a type of malicious web attack. Don’t worry about the
>   details (I don’t); just know that Rails is working hard to keep your
>   application secure.

The thing is, I'm genuinely curious. How does inserting `csrf-param` and `csrf-token` meta tags prevent CSRF? I tried Googling, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @MikhailNikalyukin Thanks (I think). That explains CSRF, which I already knew the basics of, but it doesn't explain how *meta tags* (as opposed to hidden form fields) can prevent it. Do you know the answer to that?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`csrf_meta_tag` is basically fulfilling the same thing as hidden form fields but is there to give  javascript requests that aren't tied to a form an easy way of getting the token.

If you use the [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) library the content of that meta tag is automatically added (as a request header) to any ajax requests made.

Comment: Short and sweet. You answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: Just to complete: [this article](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tour-of-rails-jquery-ujs) mentions that ujs can also use them to update outdated fragment caches. [Relevant uJS source line](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/57f4848652584f33018e46414605a873194a97d7/src/rails.js#L57). And just in case there a newbs like me wondering: `form_tag` and other helpers also add the CSRF token to the form, so they work without Js.

Answer (score 62):

The `csrf_meta_tag` inserts what is essentially a digitial signature into the page, acting as verification that requests coming into the application server are, in fact, from properly logged in users. This helps prevent cross-site scripting (a script on a completely unrelated page firing requests off to say, GMail, while you're logged into your GMail in another tab).

I guess to clarify, the `csrf_meta_tag` itself doesn't prevent an unrelated page from firing off requests to your GMail (or any other service that is the target of the attack), but the "digital signature" in the `csrf_meta_tag` is used to verify the validity of said requests. Invalid requests (i.e. from cross-site scripting attempts) should fail validation, and are therefore discarded.

To say it another way, from the attacker's point of view:

Before `csrf_meta_tags` existed (they aren't exclusive to Rails by any means), successful cross-site scripting attacks allowed a malicious site to submit data to a web app in a way that makes the request appear as if it's being done on the user's behalf. So, let's say you're an admin on a web service, and in one browser tab you're logged into the admin panel for that service. If a malicious site open in another tab targeted your service for an attack, the malicious site might be able to run scripts that make admin requests, such as dumping list of users from the database, stealing other sensitive data, or potentially harming, damaging, or destroying data contained in the service, all while appearing (from the server's standpoint) to be valid requests from the admin themselves. The `csrf_meta_tag` is a way to sign requests, and help thwart such attempts from being successful.

There's a much more detailed explanation [available here](http://www.gnucitizen.org/blog/csrf-demystified/).

It would also be educational to do a "view source" on one of your Rails-generated pages, and you'll see what the CSRF tag looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Although it was helpful and I was able to learn from it, it didn't explain how *meta tags* help with CSRF prevention (as opposed to, say, hidden form fields). But I truly appreciate your time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 17):

In Rails it will work like this way

```
def csrf_meta_tags
    if protect_against_forgery?
      [
        tag('meta', :name => 'csrf-param', :content => request_forgery_protection_token),
        tag('meta', :name => 'csrf-token', :content => form_authenticity_token)
      ].join("\n").html_safe
    end
  end
```

[See more details just click](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2cdc1f0cd5b89722e8c22bb4b26b83bd4619b28a/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/csrf_helper.rb#L19)

You also need to check [Ruby On Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html)

here is the nice [blog](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/2/8/csrf-protection-bypass-in-ruby-on-rails/)

**BUT - I prefere National Vulnerability Database, here is the good explanation**

[CWE-352: Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/352.html)

[CWE-79: Improper Neutralization of Input During Web Page Generation ('Cross-site Scripting')](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/79.html)

[Check this document for CWE - Common Weakness Enumeration](http://nvd.nist.gov/cwe.cfm#cwes)

Comment: Great links to the vulnerability database!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Although it was helpful and I was able to learn from it, it didn't explain how *meta tags* help with CSRF prevention (as opposed to, say, hidden form fields). The link to the source code explained that a little, though. Anyway, I truly appreciate your time. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Nick, I have direction of the question, I will change my answer very soon and update you. Mostly in this weekend.

Answer (score 4):

`csrf_meta_tags` are indications for ajax requests to use these as one of the form parameters to make a request to the server. Rails expects the csrf as part of your form body (params) to process your requests. Using these meta tags you can construct the form body or the csrf header to suit your needs. I hope this answer helps your question.

Answer (score 2):

Output of the helper **csrf_meta_tags**:

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="J/gw2ePXHS9Z1SUSSeUQgMmPhsPEFlFbMrLTLFHLfKjeWh7g4uyOnBlfKnlZlmCBiALDWdDWCSo1z0tybGVtfA==" />
```

This token can be included in ajax request.
Exapmle ([jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)):

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/4b6e30f68ff1244fc0c790641d3408c2695a29bd/src/rails.js#L70

```
    csrfToken: function() {
     return $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
    },

    // URL param that must contain the CSRF token
    csrfParam: function() {
     return $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content');
    },

    // Make sure that every Ajax request sends the CSRF token
    CSRFProtection: function(xhr) {
      var token = rails.csrfToken();
      if (token) xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
    },
```