# About some tags in rails program

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have got this program in ruby editor.My output comes out to be

```
<html>
<head><title> Ruby on Rails tutorial Sample App | <%= @title %></title>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

what is the error here and what is yield and csrf_meta_tag?

Comment: I don't know - what _is_ the error here (what's going wrong?)

Comment: `yield` will render the view for the current controller action and `csrf_meta_tag` will output the csrf meta tag. What error are you seeing?

Comment: As for what `csrf_meta_tag` is doing - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understand-rails-authenticity-token) on what it's preventing, and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996665/rails-how-does-csrf-meta-tag-work) on how.

Comment: i'm getting answer as :<%= csrf_meta_tag %> <%= yield %> on browser window

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be using a server to render the views, it seems like you are rather loading the html directly on your browser.

Maybe the following link will help you get started:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to rename your file from:
`application.html` to be `application.html.erb` so that it is going to interpret your embedded ruby commands.

Answer (score 0):

Ref [`yield`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield) & [`content_for`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method)

Within the context of a layout, yield identifies a section where content from the view should be inserted. The simplest way to use this is to have a single yield, into which the entire contents of the view currently being rendered is inserted:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also create a layout with multiple yielding regions:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <%= yield :head %>
  </head>
  <body>
  <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

The main body of the view will always render into the unnamed yield. To render content into a named yield, you use the content_for method.