# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a popup box name "Delete My account" where I am getting the password and delete account this password, below is the button where I click to open popup box:

```
<table align="center" width="100%">
      <tr>
         <td>    
            <div class="btn_delmyaccount" align="center">
                <a id="DeleteMyAccount" class="buttonSearch">Delete My Account</a>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

by using this javascript, open popup box:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var e2=document.getElementById("DeleteMyAccount");
                e2.onclick = show_dialog3;
                function show_dialog3() {
                $( "#dialog2" ).dialog();
                }
</script>
```

And below is he popup form:

```
<div id="dialog2" title="Delete My Account" hidden="true">
                <%= form_tag({ controller: "settings", action: "delete_my_account"}, remote: "true" ) do |f| %>
                    <table style="text-align:center; vertical-align:top;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <%= label_tag(:password, "Password") %>
                                    <%= password_field :tf_password, :placeholder => "Password" %>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table align="center" width="63%">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:right;">
                                <%= submit_tag 'Submit', :id => "_button1" %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                <% end %>
</div
```

And below is javascript for submitting the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // '_button' is the Id of your submit button
    $("#_button1").click(function() {            
      $(this).closest("form").submit();
      $("#dialog2").dialog("close");
    });
});
</script>
```

And problem is that when I click submit button on the popup box, I am getting an error below:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

To resolve this issue I add `authenticity_token: "true"` in form like below:

```
<%= form_tag({ controller: "settings", action: "delete_my_account" , authenticity_token: "true" }, remote: "true" ) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

After that still I am getting another error below:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

Kindly suggest me, what should I do to resolve this issue, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364492/actioncontrollerinvalidauthenticitytoken), the problem is typically with the [CSRF tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996665/rails-how-does-csrf-meta-tag-work) in Rails

They suggest including the csrf meta tags in your `application` layout. Do you have this:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```