# Is it insecure to include meta tags as normal HTML in the Rails application.html.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, security, heroku, meta-tags

I am currently having trouble with a twitter-bootstrap view on my heroku app. I think that `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` will make the mobile design of my app responsive. Any suggestions on this? Does this show any possible security issues? I am concerned after reading [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996665/rails-how-does-csrf-meta-tag-work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That meta tag is fine and has nothing to do with [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) which is mentioned in the linked post. Your meta tag is simply dictating the scale of the website when displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there are no issues here. `csrf_meta_tag` is a special meta tag created with a Rails helper, and generates HTML as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9997773/4624718) example.

Your responsive initial scale meta tag is a completely different meta tag, and has nothing to do with the `csrf_meta_tag`.