# Rails & Haml: cant get a form to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

I have a form:

```
  %form{:action:method => "post"}
    %fieldset
      %label{:for => "title"} Title:
      %input{:name => "title", :type => "text", :value => ""}/
      %label{:for => "notes"} Notes:
      %input{:name => "notes", :type => "text", :value => ""}/
    %a.finish{:href => "/rotas", :method => "post"} Finish!
```

However, the link does not seem to want to work - maybe I am missing something basic in Haml, or in Rails.

I have a :resource rotas in my routes.rb and my controller has a def create method.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

btw. I generated using scaffold - and it seems that the same form is used for edit a model and for a creation. How does it know whether to do a POST or a PUT?

Comment: Note: I updated my answer, I thought the problem was simple at first then realized you had more issues going on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) You want to put the target of the form in the action:

```
%form{ :action => "/rotas", :method => "post" }
```

2) You want a submit button, not a link. Try this:

```
%input{ :type => "submit" } Finish!
```

Also, I'm not sure why you're putting a `/` after your inputs, that's not needed for anything. I don't think it hurts, but I see no reason to include it.

3) Lastly, the Rails convention is not to use haml elements but rather form helpers, which would look like this:

```
= form_tag '/rotas' do
  = field_set_tag do
    = label_tag :title, 'Title:'
    = text_field_tag :title
    = label_tag :notes, 'Notes:'
    = text_field_tag :notes
    = submit_tag 'Save Changes'
```

One reason for this is Rails is going to include a hidden [Authenticity Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understand-rails-authenticity-token) field in the form for you, and normally Rails controllers won't accept forms that are submitted without this authenticity token value. This is to prevent [Cross-Site Request Forgery](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf).

Try this and see what you get.

See the [FormTagHelper API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-field_set_tag) for reference.

Comment: that did not do it - however, I got it working another way ... check out my answer

Comment: i just got it working - i have posted it as an answer - what do you reckon?

Comment: if you add the submit_tag 'Save Changes' as I have done in my answer ill mark your answer as accepted ;)

Comment: Good, glad you got it fixed. I realized twice that there was more important info to add to the answer, so now I think it's at its final version (including submit tag). Sorry to keep changing it on you!

Comment: Lol we're commenting at almost exactly the same time but page loads make these appear out of order. Submit tag is added, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the following code:

```
  = form_tag rotas_path do
    = label :rota, :name, 'Name'
    = text_field :rota, 'name'
    = submit_tag 'Save Changes'
```