# Passing data to a ruby on rails app from curl from the shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, curl

Using `curl` from the shell sending a GET to a Ruby on Rails app works like a charm.  However, with PUT, POST, etc. there is the CSRF token to contend with.  I can't seem to get the right syntax in the shell (or in PHP for that matter) for passing this data.  I think it should be something like

`curl -v -XPUT -i http://my-server:8080/some_command --data "somevalue=1" --data-urlencode X-CSRF-Token=$AUTH`

but that doesn't work.  (nor does `authenticity_token=$AUTH`)

Note that AUTH is set to the session variable shown in the browser when a browser load of this page is done.

When I do this, I get a 302 redirect to the login page.

The log says,

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity 
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
```

and then it redirects me to the login page (302).

Comment: If you get redirect to login page I think the problem is not with CSRF. What does the log say?

Comment: Sorry, should have posted that detail.  Question updated.

Comment: In my Rails app in generated forms I have `<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="XYuuLw4QBeBgp3tmykR6daZnsmMNOP8qcz4BLFZgINY=">` so if adding `authenticity_token=TOKEN` to data doesn't work for you that means you have wrong token

Comment: Refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understand-rails-authenticity-token that should light things up

Comment: TLDR: you can't use token from another session.

Answer (score 0):

you can set your controller actions to skip authenticity_token checks (you may or may not want to do this?)

```
# skip CSRF checking for json requests
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, 
  :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
```