# Required parameter missing - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, strong-parameters

I have these relevant controller models:

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController

  def vendor_params
      params.require(:vendor).permit(:id, :name, :address, :image, :latitude, :longitude)
  end

  def create
      vendor = Vendor.create(vendor_params)
      flash[:success] = "Vendor Created"
      redirect_to vendors_mgmt_path
  end

end
```

When I try to create a new vendor object, I get the following error:

```
Required parameter missing: vendor
```

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "vendors", action: "create"}, method: "post", multipart: true) do %>
<%= text_field_tag :name, "Store Name" %>
<%= text_field_tag :address, "Store Address" %>
<%= file_field_tag :image %>
<%= submit_tag "Save", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

And my migration for the Vendor table:

```
class CreateVendors < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :vendors do |t|

    t.string :name
    t.string :address
    t.float :latitude
    t.float :longitude
    t.string :image

    t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Does anyone see a clue as to why I might be getting this error? I don't understand how `:vendor` itself is a parameter... Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Here is my updated form:

```
<%= form_for @vendor, multipart: true do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name, "Store Name" %>
<%= f.text_field :address, "Store Address" %>
<%= f.file_field :image %>
<%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm not getting this error though:

```
undefined method `merge' for "Store Name":String
```

From the searching I've done, it sounds like the rails method `merge` only works on hashes, not strings. I'm not sure why it would be trying to merge this though unless my form isn't creating a hash properly?

My new action:

```
def new
    @vendors = Vendor.all
    @vendor = Vendor.new
end
```

**Server Logs**

```
Started GET "/vendors/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-23 08:04:04 -0700
Processing by VendorsController#new as HTML
  Vendor Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" 
Rendered vendors/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `merge' for "Store Name":String):
    5: <h4>New Vendor Form</h4>
    6: 
    7: <%= form_for @vendor, multipart: true do |f| %>
    8: <%= f.text_field :name, "Store Name" %>
    9: <%= f.text_field :address, "Store Address" %>
    10: <%= f.file_field :image %>
    11: <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success" %>
  app/views/vendors/new.html.erb:8:in `block in _app_views_vendors_new_html_erb__2593637676836103609_2161482240'
  app/views/vendors/new.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_vendors_new_html_erb__2593637676836103609_2161482240'


  Rendered /Users/******/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/******/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/******/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (11.9ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "vendors", action: "create"}, method: "post", multipart: true) do %>
```

Specifically, when you "require" params using [`strong params`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) in Rails, it basically expects the [params hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885990/rails-params-explained) to be structured this way:

```
params{"vendor" => {"name":sdfadsf, "address": 23423}}
```

This can only be achieved if you use `form_for @vendor` in your new.html.erb view, as this is how Rails defines that initial value to the params hash. What your app is doing is setting the params hash as this:

```
params{"name": 234234, "address: 234324}
```

---

**Solution**

In your **`new.html.erb`** form, just use this code:

```
<%= form_for @vendor, method: "post", multipart: true) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :name, "Store Name" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :address, "Store Address" %>
    <%= file_field_tag :image %>
    <%= submit_tag "Save", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That was a great answer. Good to know that about strong parameters and forms. Would you check out the error I'm getting thrown now? I've updated my question with it.

Comment: No problem! Got any more info on that error? I can't see anywhere where you call a `merge` command, and it would be good to see any other info you can provide :)

Comment: I've never seen this error before, but from some research I did, it seems that it's something to do with the way Rails renders the form (it has bad syntax essentially). I actually think it's your "multipart" definition, which should be this: `<%= form_for @vendor, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|`

Comment: Hmmm...same error with the updated multipart def. I'll start a new question for this so I don't take this question off track, thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! I'll look for you new question & see if I can help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546040/undefined-method-merge-for-xxxxxxstring-rails-form-for Thanks!

Comment: I think the first guy (from India) got it for you - the second parameter should be an options hash, not a value!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you aren't sending your params using `form_for` correctly.  You're directly using `form_tag`, `text_field_tag`, etc which you should only do under specific circumstances because this will circumvent much of Rails' built-in functionality.  You don't need to specify a value because that automatically gets populated by what's in `@vendor`.  You can make labels to label each field as in this example:

```
<%= form_for @vendor, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, "Store Name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :address, "Store Address" %>
  <%= f.text_field :address %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

In your `new` action make sure you instantiate an empty `Vendor` object so it knows what controller/action to send the form off to when it gets submitted.

If you don't want to use labels to label the fields you can use the html5 `placeholder` attribute to give a field hint instead:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Store Name" %>
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I updated my form as above. Any idea why I'm getting thrown a `undefined method `merge' for "Store Name":String` error now?

Comment: Oh silly me ;)  `f.text_field` doesn't have a "value" parameter, it gets the value from the object of the form.  I've updated my answer.  I don't think you needed a new question for this :p

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've missed something that is not immediately obvious--

```
params.require(:vendor)
```

You are specifying that params must contain :vendor. Just remove this clause, e.g.

```
def vendor_params
  params.permit(:id, :name, :address, :image, :latitude, :longitude)
end
```

If your parameters were nested beneath `:vendor` then the `.require(:vendor)` would make sense. Take a look at your development log to see the incoming parameters (share them here if you're still having trouble).

Comment: I originally had set up my vendor_params that way, but you run into problems if you don't require(:vendor). My understanding is: there are hidden fields by default in rails forms (like authenticity_token) that won't be permitted unless you require(:vendor). From a question I asked this week:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486042/rails-not-updating-attribute)