# undefined method `merge' for "xxxxxx":String rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-geocoder

I have this form in /new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @vendor, multipart: true do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name, "Store Name" %>
<%= f.text_field :address, "Store Address" %>
<%= f.file_field :image %>
<%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

and these Vendor methods:

```
def new
    @vendors = Vendor.all
    @vendor = Vendor.new
end

def vendor_params
    params.require(:vendor).permit(:id, :name, :latitude, :longitude, :address, :image)
end
```

When I try to render the page, I get this error:

```
undefined method `merge' for "Store Name":String
Extracted source (around line #8):

5: <h4>New Vendor Form</h4>
6: 
7: <%= form_for @vendor, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
8: <%= f.text_field :name, "Store Name" %>
9: <%= f.text_field :address, "Store Address" %>
10: <%= f.file_field :image %>
11: <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

I'm not sure why `merge` is being called here. Is it in a hidden field possibly? Most of the answers I found pertaining to this error had to do with hidden fields. I'm using Geocoder to geocode lat and long after validation like so (not sure if this is relevant):

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base


    geocoded_by :address
    after_validation :geocode,
        :if => lambda{ |obj| obj.address_changed? }
end
```

Any help here is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can pass this string, you can just pass some options (a hash) http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should write like this because your 2nd parameter should be an option hash, it should not be a value..

```
<%= form_for @vendor, multipart: true do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name, :value => "Store Name" %>
<%= f.text_field :address, :value => "Store Address" %>
<%= f.file_field :image %>
<%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your form like below

```
7: <%= form_for @vendor, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
8: <%= f.text_field :name %>
9: <%= f.text_field :address %>
10: <%= f.file_field :image %>
11: <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

the second argument is part of the text_filed name which in your case will mess up your parameters