# Ember js and Rails 4 CSRF

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, ember-data

I've setup a Rails 4 app with Ember js using the gems provided on the site

gemfile

```
gem 'ember-rails'
gem 'ember-source', '1.2.0'
```

entries_controller.js.coffee

```
Tut1.EntriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend

    addEntry: ->
        entry = @store.createRecord(Tut1.Entry,
        name: @get('newEntryName')
        winner: false
    )
    entry.save()
```

I get this error on the console.

```
POST http://localhost:3000/entries 422 (OK)
```

It's posting correctly, but rails is retuning a "ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken" which is confusing to me as the host, origin and referer are the same.

```
Host:localhost:3000
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
```

Is it still cross domain? How do I authenticate this request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there a quite a lot links to that problem out there

http://blog.waymondo.com/2012-12-18-ember-dot-js-and-rails-authentication-gotchas/

```
$ ->
  token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  $.ajaxPrefilter (options, originalOptions, xhr) ->
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token)
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a cross domain request, however, the code in your application controller:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

is trying to protect against a CSRF attack. It's expecting a valid CSRF token when you post the form. There are [some more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understand-rails-authenticity-token).

An easy way to get around this problem would be to use [rails_csrf](https://github.com/abuiles/rails-csrf). It essentially requests a token from your server and then sets the appropriate headers so that the requests are then made with the right CSRF token.