# Ruby on Rails: Difference of Authenticity Token being in Header or POST

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, authenticity-token

I've just noticed it doesn't matter where I put my `Authenticity Token` when submitting a request via `AJAX`. I can either append it to the form as `POST data`, or put it into the `Header`.

Is there any difference? Especially regarding security?

Additionally:

I didn't encode the Token in `Javascript`. Am I exposed to something now?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

```
form.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
   xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', AUTH_TOKEN);
   // formData.append('authenticity_token', AUTH_TOKEN);
});
```

This is my `Javascript` adding the token to the `Header` or (commented out) to the `POST data`. `AUTH_TOKEN` is the raw key. I did not encode it in any way.

Comment: There is no different if you pass a token through data or headers. I don't understand the other part of your question, care to show some code to explain?

Comment: Thanks, just a moment ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Part one**

There is totally no difference if you pass authenticity token via GET params, POST data or request headers (POST/GET params are virtually the same in Rails).

Let's look at the code (not the best code I've ever seen but...)

```
def verified_request?
  !protect_against_forgery? || request.get? || request.head? ||
    form_authenticity_token == params[request_forgery_protection_token] ||
    form_authenticity_token == request.headers['X-CSRF-Token']
end
```

Request if valid if (any of following)

1. `protect_against_forgery?` is false
2. request is GET
3. request is HEAD
4. token in params equals one stored in session
5. token in headers equals one stored in session

I should add that token is generated for every request and stored in session for later inspection (if subsequent request is POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE)

So as you see both ways of passing authenticity token are valid.

**Part two**

Is passing raw auth token in AJAX dangerous? No, as much as passing it in a form is totally not dangerous. To explain further I will quote an excellent answer in another SO question

> Why this happens: Since the authenticity token is stored in the
>   session, the client can not know its value. This prevents people from
>   submitting forms to a rails app without viewing the form within that
>   app itself. Imagine that you are using service A, you logged into the
>   service and everything is ok. Now imagine that you went to use service
>   B, and you saw a picture you like, and pressed on the picture to view
>   a larger size of it. Now, if some evil code was there at service B, it
>   might send a request to service A (which you are logged into), and ask
>   to delete your account, by sending a request to
>   http://serviceA.com/close_account. This is what is known as CSRF
>   (Cross Site Request Forgery).

original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1571900/2422778

I still consider this question laziness/lack of patience on your side as all I wrote is very well explained both in Rails Guides and on Stack Overflow. Hope next time you will be more persistent in looking for answers before posting here.
Anyway I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the difference when you use some tool like https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project or http://www.charlesproxy.com/

That are proxies, which you can turn on locally to fiddle with your HTTP requests and responses.

Very useful for web development.

Good luck.