# What am I doing wrong with this AJAX request using a form_for in Rails 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to do a form submission through AJAX in Rails and I am not too sure what is wrong here.  I got everything to work using "remote: true" but I want to gain a better understanding of how the AJAX works with jQuery.  This is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#new_user_friendship").on("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var friendId = $("#user_friendship_friend_id").val();
    var _this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
      url: "/user_friendships",
      data: _this.serialize(),
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        friendButton.hide();
        $(".friend-request-form").html("<p>Friend request sent</p>");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I am suspecting this line `url: "/user_friendships/new?friend_id="+friendId` containing the url is the culprit of my errors.  I wrote this because a hidden field is being passed as a person's friend id but it throws a "404 error", I've also tried `url: "/user_friendships"` which doesn't return any errors but it also doesn't properly execute the Javascript as I expected.

This is the corresponding form_for that the AJAX request is sent to:

```
  <div class="friend-request-form">
      <%= form_for current_user.user_friendships.build(friend_id: @user), id: "new_user_friendship", method: :post do |f| %>

        <%= f.hidden_field :friend_id, value: @user.id  %>      
        <%= submit_tag "Send friend request", class: "button radius tiny", id: "friend-request-button" %>

      <% end %>
  </div>
```

What this form does is it sends a friend request to another user using a hidden field.

And in my user_friendships_controller.rb I have this code:

```
def create
    if params[:user_friendship] && params[:user_friendship].has_key?(:friend_id)
        @friend = User.find(params[:user_friendship][:friend_id])       
        @user_friendship = UserFriendship.request(current_user, @friend)

            respond_to do |format|
                if @user_friendship.new_record?
                    format.html do
                        flash[:error] = "There was a problem creating that friend request." 
                        redirect_to user_path(@friend)
                    end
                    format.json {render json: @user_friendship.to_json, status: :precondition_failed}

                else        
                    format.html do
                        flash[:success] = "Friend request sent"
                        redirect_to user_path(@friend)
                    end
                    format.json {render json: @user_friendship.to_json, status: :precondition_failed}
                end
            end 


    else
        flash[:error] = "Friend required"
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

If anyone can provide any suggestions or feedback that'd be great!

UPDATE:

Now that I added in `data: _this.serialize()` and changed the url to: `url: "/user_friendships"` I'm now getting a `412 (Precondition Failed)` error.  Despite this error the data is actually being saved into the database.  Does anyone know why I'm getting this `412 (Precondition Failed)` error?

Comment: Where you passing the data??

Comment: i'm passing it to the id="new_user_friendship" in the form_for

Comment: `url: "/user_friendships/new?friend_id="+friendId,` is the url path valid according to your file structure

Comment: @sanjeev Ya that's the url path/structure that was generated when I was submitting POST requests without using AJAX, just to confirm isn't that what your are supposed to pass into the "url" option in the ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something I do not understand, with the dataType json, you said that you had a precondition failed status right ? 
But you wrote

`format.json {render json: @user_friendship.to_json, status: :precondition_failed}`

So I don't think there is any problem, indeed, it seems to work fine, as you explicitly passed the status in your render command, try removing it and I think you will have a 200 (success) status instead.
Of course, you can keep the previous post ajax request, or use this short version

```
$.post(
/user_friendships', 
{ user_friendship: { friend_id: friendId } }, 
function(){
    console.log(data);
    friendButton.hide();
    $(".friend-request-form").html("<p>Friend request sent</p>");
},
'json')
```

Comment: Thank you I totally forgot about that in my controller, such a stupid mistake, thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Add a data attribute to the post params instead of passing it in the url:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/user_friendships",
  data: { user_friendship: { friend_id: friendId } }, // <<< Updated
  method: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    friendButton.hide();
    $(".friend-request-form").html("<p>Friend request sent</p>");
  }
});
```

**Update**

The url should be `/user_friendships`, assuming that you're using RESTful actions. Have a look to [this](http://old.thoughtsincomputation.com/posts/understanding-rest-in-rails-3) article about REST in Rails.

Also, when you do an AJAX request like this, your are not sending the rails authenticity tokens that are crated by the [form helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html). This may be the cause of your `412 (Precondition Failed)` error.

See: [Understanding the Rails Authenticity Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understand-rails-authenticity-token)

Comment: data: {friend_id: friendId} doesn't work I think I need to add something else, would I need to serialize the data as well?

Comment: I had not seen the user_friendship param in your controller. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Now I'm getting a 412 precondition failed error from your changes but with a url of: url: "/user_friendships/", do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Ok, that might be because of the authenticity token, I've updated the answer again.

Comment: Ya changing the dataType to "jsonp" prevents the 412 error from showing, but this line: console.log(data); and these 2 don't do anything afterwards friendButton.hide();
    $(".friend-request-form").html("<p>Friend request sent</p>"); Do you have any ideas why this might be?