# Removing utf8=✓ from Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, mongoid

I have an API that returns info straight from the database and noticed Rails is storing a utf8 check mark and the authenticity token. What is the best way to remove this before it is saved?

```
{"achievements":[{"utf8":"✓","authenticity_token":"XDzrmNqNyt6OfhWpAzu3j7LhMd/sRcr/4oLsPxRMrDY=","achievement":"Big Guns",...
```

An example of the controller code:

```
def achievements
  if params.include?(:ach)
    @achievement = Achievement.new(params[:ach])
    if @achievement.save
      redirect_to action: :achievements and return
    end
  end
end
```

Example of the view:

```
<%= form_tag '', multipart: true do %>
<div class="four columns">Name <input name="ach[achievement]" type="text" ></div>
<div class="five columns">Description <input name="ach[description]" type="text" ></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than try to write up a long post, I'll just note 3 things that should get you headed in the right direction. If it's confusing, comment and I'll explain further:

1. The `utf8=✓` is inserted into your HTML when you use the form helpers in Rails.
2. You should not be handing the entire `params` object to your model.
3. You should always build your JSON API responses from known-safe attributes.

Comment: Thanks for answering, So while saving I should put in each individual parameter or is there a way to check that extra stuff isn't being saved?

Comment: I'm confused because there isn't an authenticity_token field in the model.

Comment: @Eddie I don't know what your code is doing because you haven't shared it here. For controlling what you pass to your model: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters and for your question about the `authenticity_token`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understand-rails-authenticity-token

Comment: I added some example code but it seems like you already understand what I was doing by your response.

Comment: That `mongoid` tag explains a lot. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the key-pair from the params hash, by using in the `reject` method in the Hash class.

Example:

```
hash.reject! {|k,_| k.to_s.eql?("utf8") || k.to_s.eql?("authenticity_token") }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamic fields](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#dynamic_fields) must be enabled in the configuration.

As mentioned by coreyward, params should be selectively added to model, in this case.

This is what ended working best for me:

```
achievement_params = %w[achievement description]
@achievement = Achievement.new(params.select { |key,_| achievement_params.include? key })
```

Comment: I haven't tested this but it might be a better way to do the same thing
achievement = Achievement.new
achievement.attributes = params