# Where does rails store authenticity token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csrf, authenticity

I am trying to figure out where authenticity tokens are being stored by rails4.
On every request rails seems to generate a new token. But where are all of these tokens are stored exactly when using cookie store?
I have looked through the session variable but could not find anything.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understanding-the-rails-authenticity-token

Comment: And where are the tokens stored exactly? How can I retrieve them?

Comment: Try `authenticity_token_from_session_id` or `authenticity_token_from_cookie_session`

Comment: Where do I have to call this? I tried this in a controller, but it did not work.

Comment: I think you should explain (in your question) what you are trying to achieve, and how you have tried to go about that so far, and what the actual problem is.

Comment: I try to understand how you can have multiple different authenticity tokens on every request. How does rails know that these are valid tokens?
When reading the session[:_csrf_token] it always returns the same value.
But in the formular on every request you get another one. 
Further, you can use the same token twice and they are still valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how rails handles the storage and the validation of csrf tokens:
I was looking for this http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.
So the csrf token is stored in the session. Like I mentioned before, this token remains the same. But this token is used to generate the authenticity tokens which are shown on the forms (see http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/masked_authenticity_token).

To validate the authenticity tokens there are the methods real_csrf_token and compare_with_real_token. So there is no need to store every single generated token like I thought in the first place.