# password_digest value is unique for user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 4 with has_secure_password which has password_digest in users table.i would like to store some unique value to cookie, password_digest is unique for user in users table? how to use it as unique token? can i?

Comment: No. Generate a unique value if you need one. Don't abuse the password hash.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @JonathonReinhart

Comment: Can i use authenticity_token? which CSRF token authenticity uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JonathonReinhart said, don't re-use the password_digest, and since the [authenticity_token for CSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understanding-the-rails-authenticity-token) changes in the session for every form that is submitted, you can't use that here either. If you just need to generate a unique token for your User model, I recommend doing something like this:

```
rails generate migration AddAccessTokenToUser access_token:string:uniq:index
```

Then you can generate the token on create with a callback like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Call backs
  # ----------
  before_create :generate_access_token

  private

    def generate_access_token
      begin
        self.access_token = SecureRandom.hex
      end while self.class.exists?(access_token: access_token)
    end

end
```

The *begin-end-while* will check that the SecureRandom.hex value will always be unique in the table.

Once you have this token, you can use it in a cookie or wherever.

Comment: Thank you @rlarcombe , its really helpful answer. :)