# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Rails 5 with post only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-5, csrf-protection

I have a simple application and I'm using Rails 5.0.0.1 (the app is called simpletest - it's as simple as I can make it) in order to figure some stuff out in Rails 5. I'm getting a weird error.

Here's config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "foo#bar"
  get "dobaz" => "foo#bar"
  match "dobaz" => "foo#baz", via: :post
end
```

Here's app/controllers/foo_controller.rb

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def baz
      if session[:qux].nil? || params[:reset] == "true"
        session[:qux] = 0
      else
        session[:qux] += 1
      end
      @qux = session[:qux]
      @format = request.format
      render 'bar'

  end
end
```

And here's apps/views/foo/bar.html.erb

```
<p>Qux: <%= @qux %></p>
<p>Format: <%= @format %></p>
<form action="/dobaz" method="post">
<p>Reset:
<input type="radio" name="reset" value="true">True</input>
<input type="radio" name="reset" value="false">False</input>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I'm not using any authentication or login or anything else. I am (obviously) using the session.

When I try to actually execute the app, I get the following error on an exception page:

## ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in FooController#baz

I've checked a bunch of answers. I do have `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in apps/views/layouts/application.html.erb.

This only happens with post. With get, it works fine. However, I need to use post.

Further, there is a solution, but it doesn't make sense to me. I can add the following code to the top of my controller, which (if I understand it properly) should reset the session if the format is json, and suddenly it works:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :reset_session, if: ->{request.format.json?}
```

**but the format is text/html**! Also, the session isn't being reset (as I can tell via `session[:qux]`. Why would this have any effect? If I just use:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :reset_session
```

it works, but of course it resets the session. Using `:null_session` in place of `:reset_session` has the same effect (both with and without the if).
I've done nothing special. Other than adding code, all I've done is:

```
rails new simpletest
[copied over Gemfile]
bundle install
rails generate controller foo bar
```

I'm running ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux] on Debian 8.

Comment: When you submit the form, do you see the authenticity_token parameter? (you can see a list of parameters from the request on the error page towards the bottom)

Comment: `<input type='hidden' name='authenticity_token' value='<%= form_authenticity_token %>'>`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to use a form helper which will automatically set up a hidden input for authenticty_token.

In you view you can just use form_tag (which is the simplest helper of this type)

```
<!-- in app/views/foo/bar.html.erb -->
<%= form_tag "/dobaz" do %>
  <p>Reset:
  <input type="radio" name="reset" value="true">True</input>
  <input type="radio" name="reset" value="false">False</input>
  <input type="submit"/>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Apparently I don't qualify for upvotes that count, but for future explorers, this solution works perfectly, and along with @cdimitroulas's answer, explains why `protect_from_forgery with: :reset_session, if: ->{request.format.json?}` works, even though it doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

As jphager2 mentioned this is an issue caused by Rails' protection against CSRF(Cross Site Request Forgery) when using input forms and can be easily solved by using a form helper instead of a simple HTML form.

You can see Faisal's great answer on this topic here -> [Understanding the Rails Authenticity Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understanding-the-rails-authenticity-token)

Comment: Thanks, this really helps. There are many threads on this, and I didn't find this one (I was perhaps overfocused on the error message as search text). If I understand correctly, the reason `protext_from_forgery with:` works is that it forces the authentication token to be used. Does that seem correct?

Comment: I'm fairly new to rails but as far as I understand that is correct!