# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in DonationsController#create_user_account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csrf

I am new in ruby on rails and I am trying to send the post request using ajax to the controller method but the it throw the exception

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in DonationsController#create_user_account
```

I have google it but no idea what to do to solve this.

It is the main controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Here is the code of donations controller

```
def create_user_account
    @donation = Donation.find(params[:a])
    @pars = [@donation.a]
    print @pars
    render plain: "OK"
  end
```

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_donation
      @donation = Donation.find(params[:id])
    end

```
def set_campaign
  @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:campaign_id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def donation_params
  params.require(:donation).permit(:amount, :user_id, :campaign_id)
end
```

Comment: You're not including the CSRF token in the AJAX request

Comment: Can you share your view code?

Comment: after adding token 

$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://localhost:3000/donations/create_user_account",
        data:{a:'abc'},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data) {

     });

This error occurs

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in DonationsController#show

Couldn't find Donation with 'id'=create_user_account
Extracted source (around line #173):

The route is post 'donations/create_user_account' => 'donations#create_user_account'

Comment: Your are probably not sending the `id` (i.e. your are sending a `null` value). Check your `show` action in your controller, but the problem is likely to be in your view.

Comment: I have not defined any view. I am just trying to get values in the controller method.
I am sending data using ajax call and why I need to send id ?? I dont want to send id.

Comment: You need to send `id` because `find` method uses `id`. If you have a column named `a` just change `@donation = Donation.find(params[:a])` to `@donation = Donation.find_by(a: params[:a])`.

Comment: Same error

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in DonationsController#show

Couldn't find Donation with 'id'=create_user_account

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141775/discussion-between-john-and-gerry).

Comment: Check out this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understanding-the-rails-authenticity-token