# How do I sign in/out into a rails app's user account that use devise from terminal instead of browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm developing a rails app that use devise to manage users, and I want to prevent user from signing into my app directly. (can I just prevent it by removing all the relevant routes?)

I have removed the front end logic, but I know that browser is not the only way to access a website. People can also use tools like `curl` to access website, so I want to know how people do that so I can better prevent it.

Comment: If you have API app Without access_token no one can login  through API and every time when you submit a request or a form there is a token generated by rails.
Authenticity token is well explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understanding-the-rails-authenticity-token).

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/rubyinside/a-deep-dive-into-csrf-protection-in-rails-19fa0a42c0ef) is also good article about CSRF tokens and also refer to [rails-guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html).

Comment: @ts  can I just prevent it by removing all the relevant routes?

Comment: Yes you can prevent.