# How to pass data from ajax() to the controller Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to pass data from ajax into the controller to update user location but the getData variable return nil. I'm not sure if that is the best way but I found many solutions that recommend using ajax.

Thanks in advance

```
//order_controller
def new
@order = Order.new
@cart = @current_cart
end

def create
#  raise 'ss'
getData = params[:data_value]
@location = Geocoder.search(getData)[0]
# console
current_user.latitude = @location.latitude
current_user.longitude = @location.longitude
current_user.address = @location.address
current_user.save

order = current_user.orders.new(status: "pending")
order.item_ids = @current_cart.item_ids
order.save
@current_cart.destroy

redirect_to root_path
end


//new.html.erb
$("#buy").on('click', function(){
//  debugger;
$.ajax({
url : "/orders/",
type : "post",
data : { data_value: 'Paris' },
success: function(post){ alert('WORK') },
error: function(post){ alert('ERROR') }
});
})
<%= button_to "buy" ,  orders_path(@order) , { action: "post", id: 
"buy" }  %>


//routes.rb
post "/orders/:id", to: "orders#create"
resources :orders 
root "sellers#index"
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You are much more likely to get meaningful answers in response if you properly indent your example code.

Comment: show us the `post` request logs

Comment: @MoustafaSallam Thanks for writing. I noticed the problem. When I use Geocoder.search() it's return nil.But It works if I directly save the getData variable into current_user.address without use Geocoder.search(). Did you know why Geocoder.search() keeps return nil

Comment: @MoustafaSallam It works, I just add if condition @location.present?.

Answer (score 0):

You miss submitting the `authenticity_token` when you send the `post ajax request`

All `post` requests requires passing the `authenticity_token` as one of the `post` request parameters.

---

Read more about `authenticity_token` here

[Understanding the Rails Authenticity Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understanding-the-rails-authenticity-token)